# Background Cover Minimum Size and Centered

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to add a background to an element, however the image is very large. As a result, using background: cover leaves the image actual-size and does not center it. Thus, the image appears very "zoomed in" as it is not showing as much as it can.

So, here's the question: How can I have the image be as small as it can, while still covering the entire element. Furthermore, how can I center it properly?

Attached I have what background: cover gives me, and a simple photoshop mockup of what I want. I outlined in red where the border of the background is.

**Background: Cover with small width**

[image: Background: Cover with small width]

**Photoshop mockup with small width**

[image: Photoshop mockup with small width]

**Background: Cover with large width**

[image: Background: Cover with large width]

**Photoshop mockup with large width**

[image: Photoshop mockup with large width]

Answer (score 0):

Currently your **background-position** declaration for #home is set to **0, 0;**

Those numbers represent the x-axis (horizontal placement) and y-axis (vertical placement) for the background image. I played around with the inspector and was able to move the background image's position more to my liking. You could also try playing around with keywords if they make more sense to you

```
    background-position: top left;
```

or perhaps:

```
    background-position: center center;
```

Percentages are also an option:

```
    background-position: 25% 50%;
```

The keywords and percentages also apply to the x-axis and y-axis respectively.

Check out the MDN article for more information: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

One final note, your background image is *huge*–7.1MB to be exact. If you could get it the size down to at least 1MB (though under 500kb would be ideal), I'd totally recommend that.

Comment: Thanks! However that still doesn't address the fitting of the image. I'm very new to web development (I'm a Python/Objective C guy), so pardon me for my naiveté. What is the standard size for such a background in web development?

Comment: Hey Thor!  No need to apologize. :) There isn't a standard size. I personally try to keep images that are meant to be huge background images no larger than about 1500px in width. But more important than width is the file size. I'm on a fast wifi connection, but that bg image on your site took a few seconds to load (and a few seconds are everything in web design and development). As for the height, I always try to match the 1500px width to the aspect ratio of the image I have in my mockups and I usually use this site to calculate: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/

Comment: Additionally, is it good practice to use @media rules for providing higher quality images when needed? Thanks.

Comment: @ThorCorreia The idea of using media queries for providing higher quality images is highly debated. Mainly because of the fact that even though the images can't be _seen_, all of them have to be loaded on the user's browser. So if you have 6 images, and 5 are hidden by media queries, all 6 images still have to load within the user's browser which can slow down the user's experience when using your site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could help since I have not tried it; however, basically there is a property called 
background-size:  and the size  can be in % 
so if you want the background image to be 50% ( width and height ) or 50% 75% ( width and height) of the or certain size you want

see [documentation background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)   also see [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Examples)

Hope this could help
Alan Mehio
London